# How to return coordinates of my location using LocationDisplayManager (ESRI API)?

Tags: java, android, arcgis-android

I'm trying to create an application which works with lat and long of a device position. I'm using [*LocationDisplayManager* class](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/LocationDisplayManager.html) to find and to map a location.

```
MapView mMapView = null;

public void getPos(MapView mMapView) {
    LocationDisplayManager loc = mMapView.getLocationDisplayManager();
    loc.setAutoPanMode(LocationDisplayManager.AutoPanMode.LOCATION);
    loc.start();
}

public void showPos(View view) {
    getPos(mMapView);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

    if(getLon(mMapView) < 55.00 && getLat(MapView) < 55.00){
        TextView itemLoc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLoc);
        itemLoc.setText("Lon: " + getLon(mMapView) + " Lat: " + getLon(mMapView));
    // code...
    }
}
```

I cannot return numerical values of lat and long that I need for future manipulations
I tried to implement the following code:

```
public double getLon(MapView mMapView) {
    LocationDisplayManager loc = mMapView.getLocationDisplayManager();
    return loc.getLocation().getLongitude();
}
public double getLat(MapView mMapView) {
    LocationDisplayManager loc = mMapView.getLocationDisplayManager();
    return loc.getLocation().getLatitude();
}
```

It gives error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at this line: **return loc.getLocation().getLongitude();**

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement OnStatusChangedListener and LocationListner to get what you want.

Take a look at this example:

https://developers.arcgis.com/android/sample-code/nearby/